# Translation of Set Builder notation to natural language

Tags: notation, logic-translation

I am wondering about the (very basic) translation of this symbolic set builder notation into natural language:

$$\{n \in \mathbb{Z} : (\exists k \in  \mathbb{Z} )[n = 2k]\}$$

It's very intuitively obvious to me that this is the set of all even integers. My English translation would be: "The set of all integers, n, such that there exists an integer, k, **such that** n is two times k".

I have a number of sub questions from this: 
(1) Is the translation correct? Specifically is it fine to have the second 'such that'?
(2) If the second 'such that; is correct, then why isn't the symbolic notation written as $$\{n \in \mathbb{Z} : (\exists k \in  \mathbb{Z}:n = 2k)\}$$

Is there something special about using regular parentheses for $(\exists k \in  \mathbb{Z})$, but square parentheses for $[n = 2k]$ that indicates there is a statement 'such that' in between?

Thanks very much.

Comment: The general form of the [Set-builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation#Sets_defined_by_a_predicate) is : $\{ x \mid \varphi(x) \}$ and reads : "the set of all and only those objects such that $\varphi$ holds of them".

Comment: Thus, all amounts to correctly specifying the formula $\varphi$ : $\{ n \mid n \in \mathbb Z \text { and } \exists k (k \in \mathbb Z \text { and } (n=2k)) \}$.

Comment: It reads : "the set of all and only those integers $n$ such that $n=2k$, for some integer $k$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your translation is correct.  Good job!

The reason there isn't traditionally a second colon in that is because that inner part isn't a set.  You could make that part a set if you wrote something like $$\{n\in\mathbb Z:\{k\in\mathbb Z:n=2k\}\neq\emptyset\}$$ but I think the quantifier is more clear about what it's saying.

Different authors have different ways of separating quantifiers like $\exists$ from the logical statement.  In your sentence, you used parentheses, which is common.  I've also seen people using colons for it, so a reasonable person would have no trouble interpreting your second statement correctly as well.  Some of your growth as a mathematician is finding a writing style that captures your personal style of balancing clarity versus brevity, so you're asking the right questions!

Comment: Thanks very much! I think I understand the latter part of your answer, but I'm not sure I follow your example of the set. To satisfy the predicate $\{ k \in \mathbb{Z} : n = 2k \} \neq \emptyset$, satisfied so long as there is at least one $n$ that satisfies the inner predicate, $n = 2k$ ? In this example, how do we know the set is the set of all even integers, and not just the set of at least one even integer?

Comment: @masiewpao We know that the (outer) set is the set of all even integers because the inner set for those cases would not be empty.  For instance, when $n=6$, the inner set would be $\{3\}$, which is empty.  But if $n=5$, the inner set would be empty because there is no integer $k$ such that $2k=5$.

Comment: Ahh I'm very sorry, I see what you mean! Thank you very much!